# Reset every file to HEAD except those in stage git

Tags: git, reset, head, stage

Let's say `foo.c` is staged and `bar.c` has been modified but is not staged. Is there a way to get every non-staged file, which in this case is `bar.c`, reset back to HEAD without `foo.c` getting out of stage ?

I know that commiting won't write bar's changes in history I would just like to avoid commiting since I am building a script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[S. KUMAR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49182879/1256452), which you have accepted, is generally correct for what you intend.  It's worth noting several details though.

Remember that there are *three* active copies every file as far as `git status` is concerned:

- `foo.c` exists in HEAD (`HEAD:foo.c`), in the index / staging-area (`:0:foo.c`), and in the work-tree (`foo.c`).
- `bar.c` exists in HEAD (`HEAD:bar.c`), in the index / staging-area (`:0:bar.c`), and in the work-tree (`bar.c`).

When you say:

> Let's say `foo.c` is staged and `bar.c` has been modified but is not staged ...

what you *mean*, in Git terms anyway, is:

- `HEAD:foo.c` != `:0:foo.c`, but `:0:foo.c` == `foo.c`
- `HEAD:bar.c` == `:0:bar.c`, but `:0:bar.c` != `bar.c`

Note that it's possible to have all three copies of any one file differ from each other, and you get this quite normally by using `git add -p` for instance.  If you ran `git add -p bar.c` and selected some, but not all, of the patch hunks, you'd end up with this state.

When you run `git status`, Git first diffs `HEAD`-vs-index and reports whatever is different as *changes staged for commit*.  It then diffs index-vs-work-tree and reports whatever is different as *changes not staged for commit* (and potentially reports untracked files as well).

---

Running:

```
git checkout <path>
```

tells Git to copy the *index* (aka staging-area) version of the file to the *work-tree*.  That is, for every file matching `<path>`, copy `:0:<path>` to `<path>`.

Given your setup above, this overwrites `foo.c` from `:0:foo.c`, which leaves `foo.c` unchanged.  It also overwrites `bar.c` from `:0:bar.c`, which changes `bar.c` back to what is in `HEAD:bar.c`, since `:0:bar.c` matched (and still matches) `HEAD:bar.c`.

---

It's also worth mentioning that running:

```
git reset <path>
```

tells Git to copy the `HEAD` version of the file(s) to the index.  This leaves the work-tree alone.  You can work out for yourself what this does to `:0:foo.c` and `:0:bar.c`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can git checkout every file from your project folder. This won't affect any staged files.

> git checkout .